# best way to pass core data values

Tags: core-data, tableview, fetch

Im developing a golf score recording app with three view controllers.
The first view controller is a table view controller that has each round that you play via an add round button. When you click a golf round(cell) it takes you to a new view controller that has 18 buttons correlating to each  hole of that round. When you click on a hole button (i.e. Hole 1), it then pushes you to a new 3rd view controller where you can record values such as the Par of that hole, the yardage, and then also text fields to input each players score(all this being stored via core data).

Here is my dilemma. Im using core data to persist all the data. Im curious on what the best way to populate text labels on my 3rd view controller with information from my first view controller. Right now I am using the prepareForSegue function to create instances of the new view controllers and then setting the properties of the new view controllers via the prepareForSegue function.

This works just dandy. however, when i get to the third View controller i want to populate some of my fields with some of the data that corresponds to that round. And because the third VC is not a table view I'm lost at how to make sure its fetching the correct data from the correct corresponding indexPath. Right now I'm just passing values from the tableview through properties in the 2nd VC, and then passing those properties again to the 3rd VC. Is there a way i can just do a fetch request on a specific index path if I'm not on the tableview VC?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure probably looks something like this (or should):

```
Course (.rounds) <------>> Round (.course)
Round   (.holes) <------>> Hole  (.round)
```

You press on a row in the list of holes, simply pass the select `Hole` to the final view controller. If you need any information from any of the superordinate entities, simply use dot notation.

```
NSString *nameOfCourse = self.hole.round.course.name;
```

No need to fetch, no need to communicate with any other view controllers! How swell is that?

Comment: thanks mundi ill go ahead and try to implement this.